# How to style HTML5 <meter> tag in 2014

Tags: css, html, tags, meter

This question is simply a more recent version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094835/how-to-style-html5-meter-tag).

I'm asking it again because:

1. All the answers come with the caveat that "at the moment, there isn't much support", and are a few years old, so I'm guessing (hoping, really) that there's been some change, and
2. the consensus seems to be that questions with dated answers should be [re-asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252520/mark-questions-or-answers-as-out-of-date#answer-252522) to reopen dialogue.

So, has there been any change? It seems idiotic that this awesome tag would exist, but that there would be only one way to display it.

### Codicil:

I know how to do basic stuff like:

```
meter
{  
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    border-radius: 0.75em;
    overflow:hidden;
    /**/
}
```

What I want to know is more meter-specific CSS information.

Comment: @JohnConde Specifically stated as a 'duplicate' but see the OP's comments.

Comment: [**CSS-Tricks Article 11/2013**](http://css-tricks.com/html5-meter-element/)

Comment: Re-asking the question isn't really encouraged here.

Comment: Not encourged I understand but see [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252520/mark-questions-or-answers-as-out-of-date#answer-252522). It is off-topic though. :)

Comment: @JohnConde Generally true. [But not in this case.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252520/mark-questions-or-answers-as-out-of-date#answer-252522)

Comment: This question does not meet all of the set forth criteria. I don't think this is a question that needs to be re-asked.

Comment: Fair enough. Seems reasonable.

Comment: @JohnConde It may be that the answers aren't out of date, but the problem I'm having is that, without knowing the current answers, I don't know that the old ones are still valid. It's been 3 years. That's the only reason I re-asked; if there's been no change, I don't object to closing as a dupe.

Comment: Try them and see. Try lots of things and see. Also look at websites that show browser support for html5 elements. They'll be informative.

Comment: @JohnConde Ah- right. I should have been clearer about what I mean by "out of date"; I don't mean that the information they contain is no longer valid; I just mean that it may be incomplete due to age. The answers are mostly dependent on extensions (WebKit, Mozilla). I was hoping there might be a more standard way since then.